# PersistenceContext and EJB transaction boundary

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

i am struggling with the following thing:

i have a stateless bean as a repository for a entity, this bean has a entity manager declared.

When i call this bean from another stateless bean , a entity is returned, then if a call a relation in this new returned entity a exception is thrown for "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role". As i understand, the persistence context its attached to the transaction, or create a new one if transaction doesnt exist, but in this case, the transaction exist and its started in the client stateless bean that calls the repository bean.

here its a simple example:

```
@Entity
public class Config{

     Long id;
     String description;

     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="equipment")
     private Equipment equipment;
}

@Entity
public class Equipment{
    Long id;
    String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipment")
    Config config;
}

@Stateless
public class EquipmentRepo{

    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager em;

    public Equipment find(Long id) {
        return em.find(Equipment.class, id);    
    }

}

@Stateless
public class ServiceFacade {

    @Inject
    EquipmentRepo repo;

    public List<Config> findEquipmentConfig(Long id) {
        Equipment element = repo.find(id);
        List<Config> configurations = element.getConfig();
        return configurations;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The lazy initialization also requires an active transaction. If you were to check carefully, the cause of the exception would be something to do with missing transaction.

When the stateless method returns, the active transaction is ended, and since the transaction is container managed, hibernate expects an active transaction when you call the entity method to load the referenced lazy loaded properties.

This problem is normally solved by ensuring that your entity domains are not used beyond the transaction/service level. When a service returns, it should return a dto of the mapped entity, with required fields. In this case therefore, if you require the lazy loaded properties, it will still be executed within the same transaction and mapped to your own dto.

Comment: Hi maress, thanks for your reply.

I understand, but is i said, there is a stateless bean ( beanA) that call another stateless bean by injection (beanB), and then beanB retrieve a entity. The transacttion start on beanA according to the specification, and when beanB is called, he attach himself to the current transacction and return the entity to beanA, so all the way up the transacction is still running.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm assuming that your `Equipment` class should look like:

```
@Entity
public class Equipment{
    Long id;
    String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipment")
    List<Config> config;
}
```

i.e `config` should be a collection.

`@OneToMany` relationships are lazily initialised by default.

When you execute:

```
Equipment element = repo.find(id);
```

it returns a single `Equipment` object that has a collection of `Config` proxies rather the entities themselves.

If you iterated over the `element.config` within the `findEquipmentConfig` method then the JPA implementation would load each Config entity as it is referenced.
This works because the entity manager and transaction are still active.

But you're iterating from the method that called `findEquipmentConfig` which I imagine is a servlet or some other kind of web controller that has no transactional context active.
Therefore you get the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

At this point you might be considering adding a dummy load loop to preload all the configs.

But this is a bad idea because it leads to the infamous N+1 SELECT problem and an application that scales poorly. If an equipment entity had a 1000 config items associated with it then your application will execute 1001 SELECT statements to load the object (the extra one is to load the initial Equipment entity).

It is in fact one of the motivations for the `join fetch` query syntax that is available in JPA QL.

You can change your `find` method so that it looks something like:

```
public Equipment find(Long id) {
    TypedQuery<Equipment> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT e FROM Equipment e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.config WHERE e.id = :id", Equipment.class);
     return query.setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
}
```

This will ensure that all of your equipment config is loaded at once.

Comment: Hi, thats not the case... the method that call findEquipmentConfig is a ejb, so the transaction must be alive.

Comment: Please add a stack trace. There's something you're not telling us. Also, did you try changing your query anyway? You will get better performance